# Saving matrix field of a duplicate of an entry not working

Tags: craft3

I'm creating a cron job to automatically import new entries (vacancies).
I have an entry that I use as a template with some standard data fields and matrix fields. If it's an entry that has not been imported before I create a new entry as a duplicate of the template entry.

```
$entry = Craft::$app->getElements()->duplicateElement($entryTemplate);
```

The template already has the matrix blocks but only placeholder data that I want to overwrite like this:

```
// existing matrix fields (already created or from template)
$matrixBlocks = $entry->myMatrixBlock;

/** @var MatrixBlock $matrixBlock */
foreach($matrixBlocks as $matrixBlock) {
    $matrixBlock->setFieldValues(['contactText' => 'random text']);

    $success = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($matrixBlock);
}
```

The strange thing is that the ownerId of the matrixBlock isn't the value of the $entry->id nor is it the value of the template id. It generated a new ownerId.
It works correctly when I import it a second time because the owner id is now correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds suspiciously like a bug that was fixed in today's [Craft 3.6.10](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#3610---2021-03-09) release.

> Fixed a bug where entries could return the wrong Matrix/Neo/Super Table blocks if the blocks were queried immediately after the entry was created via `craft\services\Elements::duplicateElement()`.

My guess is if you update to that release, it'll behave like you expect now.

Comment: Yes I contacted craft support with this question and it was indeed this bug. They fixed it right away.